# Log out user from php session

Tags: php, session

When a user is logged in, I want them to have a button to log out and be redirected to the page they are on, however, with a few additional features, which are called. Unfortunately, nothing happens when the log out button is pressed.

This is the code for the logout.php file.

```
<input type="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log out">
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
       session_start();
       $_SESSION = array();
       if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
       $yesterday = time() - (24 * 60 * 60); $params = session_get_cookie_params();            
       setcookie(session_name(), '', $yesterday,
       $params["path"], $params["domain"],
       $params["secure"], $params["httponly"] );
     }
     session_destroy();
     header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
   }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Redirect user to a logout php script (logout.php)
2. Continue the session by calling `session_start()`
3. Check if `$_SESSION['uname']` is empty or not... if empty then destroy the session by calling `session_destroy()`
4. Redirect the user back to the home page `header("/")`

//HTML

```
<a href="logout.php">logout</a>
```

-or-

```
<input type="button" value="Logout" onclick="window.location.href = 'logout.php';">
```

-or-

```
<button onclick="window.location.href = 'logout.php';">Logout</button>
```

//LOGOUT.PHP

```
<?php
//continue current session
session_start();
//check to see if session variable (uname) is set
//if set destroy the session
if(!empty($_SESSION['uname'])){
    session_destroy();
}
//redirect the user to the home page
header("Location: /");
?>
```

Comment: @Jules I used $_SESSION['userid'] for an example... that's how I identified my users... I'm guessing yours is a little different. What session variable are you using to identify your users?

Comment: The session variable I'm using is $_SESSION['uname']

Comment: It looks like this now, is that how it's supposed to look? I guess not.

Comment: <input type="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log out">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
$yesterday = time() - (24 * 60 * 60); $params = session_get_cookie_params(); setcookie(session_name(), '', $yesterday,
$params["path"], $params["domain"],
$params["secure"], $params["httponly"] );
}
session_destroy();


}
?>
<meta name="Refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"/>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Sorry got confused between you two :-)

Comment: @Jules yea no...  so forget the code you have, and think about the goal your trying to accomplish which is destroying the user's session based off the users action (user-click). From what you mentioned above, the way you identify your users is from the $_SESSION['uname'] variable, so all you need to do is destroy it. So simply redirect the user to another PHP script which checks if the $_SESSION['uname'] variable is not empty and if it's not empty implying that it's set and that user has in active-session then call session_destroy()... then simply redirect the user to the home page header();

Comment: Hello I was able to figure it out. There was no form around my button. It's working now, this is what it looks like:

Comment: <form method = "post">
<input type="submit" type="submit" name="logout" value="Log out">
</form>

Comment: @Jules yea you were using a input type submit without form... but regardless you shouldn't use a form if the user isn't entering any data... Use any of the three examples I posted above.

Comment: yeah I also separated the function from the form. It's working fine now. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Jules yea no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Just save it as "**login.php**" and access from the browser. UserId is "**user**" and Password is "**pass**".

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php if ( array_key_exists( 'uid', $_SESSION ) ): ?>
    <?php /* if $_SESSION['uid'] is set, user is already logged in */ ?>
    <?php if ( array_key_exists( 'cmd', $_GET ) && $_GET['cmd']==='logout' ): ?>
        <?php
            unset( $_SESSION[ 'uid' ] );
            unset( $_SESSION[ 'error' ] );
            session_destroy();
        ?>
        <h1>See you soon!</h1>
        Click 
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?r=<?php echo md5(uniqid(rand())); ?>">here</a>
        if you don&#39;t get redirected automatically within 5 seconds.
        <script type="text/javascript">
            setTimeout( function() { 
                location.href = "<?php echo addslashes( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ); ?>?r=<?php echo md5(uniqid(rand())); ?>"; 
              }, 5000 );
        </script>
    <?php else: ?>
        <h1>You are logged in</h1>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?cmd=logout&amp;r=<?php echo md5(uniqid(rand())); ?>">Log Out</a> | 
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?r=<?php echo md5(uniqid(rand())); ?>">Refresh</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php /* user is not logged in */ ?>
    <?php if ( strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post' ): ?>
        <?php
            // login (POST) request, let's check if credentials 
            // are correct
            unset( $_SESSION['error'] );
            if ( array_key_exists( 'userid', $_POST ) && array_key_exists( 'passwd', $_POST ) )
                {
                    $userid = trim( $_POST['userid'] );
                    $passwd = trim( $_POST['passwd'] );
                    if ( $userid === '' )
                        {
                            $_SESSION['error'] = 'No userid supplied';
                        }
                    elseif ( $passwd === '' )
                        {
                            $_SESSION['error'] = 'No password supplied';
                        }
                    elseif ( $userid !== 'user' || $passwd !== 'pass' )
                        {
                            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Wrong userid or password';
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            $_SESSION['uid'] = $userid;
                            // from now on, the user is logged in
                        }
                }
            else
                {
                    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Missing userid or password';
                }

            // redirect the user anyways
            // this gets rid of posted data if this was a POST,
            // so when user reloads the page it doesn't try to
            // re-authenticate
            // Can be a different URL if user is logged in 
            // successfully
            header( 'Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?r=' . md5(uniqid(rand())) );
            exit;
        ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php /* user not logged in, let's display login form */ ?>
        <h1>Log In</h1>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <label for="user-id">User Id</label>
            <input type="text" name="userid" id="user-id" />
            <label for="user-pwd">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="passwd" id="user-pwd" />
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
        </form>
        <?php /* in case any errors occured, show them */ ?>
        <?php if ( array_key_exists( 'error', $_SESSION ) && $_SESSION['error'] ): ?>
            <div class="error-msg"><?php echo $_SESSION['error']; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In any other (PHP) page of your site, you can then restrict access to authenticated users by checking:

```
<?php
    if ( array_key_exists( 'uid', $_SESSION ) )
        {
            /* user is logged in, do whatever */
        }
    else
        {
            /* user is NOT logged in, do whatever else */
        }
?>
```

Comment: is that the full code of your logout.php or not? looks like the one you have posted is missing a <form> tag?

Comment: Also, sometimes setcookie and session_destroy don't work properly if used with header:location redirects. Try `<meta name="Refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"/>` instead of your header:location.

Comment: <input type="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log out"> <?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ session_start(); $_SESSION = array(); if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) { $yesterday = time() - (24 * 60 * 60); $params = session_get_cookie_params(); setcookie(session_name(), '', $yesterday, $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"] ); } session_destroy(); } ?> <meta name="Refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"/> </body> </html>

Comment: Just added a fully working solution. Just save it as "login.php" and access from the browser. UserId is "user" and Password is "pass".